# Rancher - Is it possible to spin-up / recreate an entire namespace available in one environment on a new environment

Tags: namespaces, yaml, containers, rancher, rancher-rke

Rancher: v2.2.4

In Rancher GUI, I see on one of our environment (Dev) and it contains a namespace '**n1**'. This namespace under different sections (i.e. Workloads, LoadBalancers, ConfigMaps, Volumes etc) have few entries (containers/settings etc).

I want to create the same namespace on a new environment where Rancher is running. This environment lets say is (Test). After getting all the required docker images (`sudo docker image pull <server:port>/<imagename:imageversion>`), do I need to download YAMLs of all these entries under each sections and import them to the target environment? (possibly changing **volumes-id**, **container image entries i.e. `name: <server:port>/<imagename:imageversion>`** locations (if any), **controller-uid** to keep the one on the target (TEST) environement)? My understanding is, if I create a new workload/add anything under a respective section, the label/annotations will generate a fresh controller-id value! so, I'm wondering before importing the YAML, if I should leave the controller-uid entry value blank (not sure if it'll barf).

Is there a simple way to spin up/create an entire namespace **'n1'** on **TEST** environment (i.e. namespace replica of *n1* Dev in Test) with auto-generating the necessary Storage bits (volume classes/volumes and persistent volumes - all of these have some Vol ID/name/uid associated with each entity), Deployments bits (uid/controller-uids) etc?

What's an **efficient way** to do this so that I don't have to manually download YAMLs (from Dev) and import them in Test at each component level (i.e. ***Volumes YAMLs, Volume Class YAML, Workloads/Deployment YAMLs etc - one by one***)?

Comment: this may be a very bad suggestion, but .. you can hack at this https://github.com/pieterlange/kube-backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to grab all resources from a namespace and apply them in a new namespace.

```
#!/bin/bash
SourceNamespace="SourceNS"
TargetNamespace="TargetNS"
TempDir="./tmp"

echo "Grabbing all resources in $SourceNamespace"
for APIResource in `kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name`
do
  kubectl -n "$SourceNamespace" get "$APIResource" -o yaml > "$TempDir"/"$APIResource".yaml
done

echo "Deploying all resources in $TargetNamespace"
for yaml in `ls $TempDir`
do
  kubectl apply -n "$TargetNamespace" -f "$TempDir"/"$yaml"
done
```